# How to put labels on new pull request using github3.py?

Tags: python, python-3.x, api, github, github3.py

I saw that github3.py still doesn't have the attribute labels on Repository.create_pull() as in Repository.create_issue(). But there is the property labels on ShortPullRequest created. So I tried:

```
created_pr = repo.create_pull(
    title=pr.title,
    body=pr.body,
    head=pr.head,
    base=pr.base,
)
if pr.labels:
    created_pr.labels = pr.labels
    created_pr.update()
```

The problem is that after I check on GitHub, the PR was created with no labels. Is there any solution for this using this component?

Note: I can't use pygithub since they use LGPL Licence and I want to make MIT Licence code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, the way to do it is:

```
if pr.labels:
    issue = created_pr.issue()
    issue.add_labels(*pr.labels)
```

Thanks @sigmavirus24 on Github.